# How share a screenshot to Facebook using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-share

I need to have a Facebook share button on one of my app's view controllers so that when the user pushes it, it will share a screenshot of the user's current screen to Facebook.

I have been watching a few tutorials such as this one on how to implement a Facebook share button: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=774_-cTjnVM

But these only show how I can share a message on Facebook, and I'm still a little bit confused how to share the whole screen that user is currently interacting with.

Comment: Do you mean you want to share literally what the user sees, i.e. a screenshot?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want to do.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Sharing directly to Facebook isn't hard to do. First, import the `Social` framework:

```
import Social
```

Now add this as the action for your button:

```
let screen = UIScreen.mainScreen()

if let window = UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screen.bounds.size, false, 0);
    window.drawViewHierarchyInRect(window.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
    let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    let composeSheet = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
    composeSheet.setInitialText("Hello, Facebook!")
    composeSheet.addImage(image)

    presentViewController(composeSheet, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

You might be interested to know that `UIActivityViewController` lets users share to Facebook but also other services. The code above is for your exact question: sharing to Facebook. This code renders the *entire* visible screen; you can also have individual views render themselves if you want.

Note: As Duncan C points out in a comment below, this rendering code won't include anything outside your app, such as other apps or system controls.

Comment: The best answer I could ever get for this question! Thanks a lot TwoStraws. Time to go and study the working code I have furthermore, now :)

Comment: You're welcome! At the very least I hope I've given you some good pointers for things to Google if it only 95% solves your problem. Good luck!

Comment: Point of order: That code will render your app's entire window contents, but not anything that belongs to another app or to the system.

Comment: @DuncanC You're right; I shall clarify that in my answer. I was very impressed, in the same vein, how ReplayKit automatically filters out secure information in a similar way.

Comment: Your code doesn't show the title in the share pop up

Comment: Great answer I am really appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

In iOS 8 and earlier there used to be a private framework that you could use to capture the entire screen. Using that framework would cause your app to be rejected for the app store, but at least it worked.

Starting in iOS 9 that API no longer works

The best you can do is to capture your app's views. That won't include the status bar or other things drawn by the system or other apps.

One way is to create an off-screen context, render the parent view you want to capture into the off-screen context (probably using `drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:`, load the data from the context into a UIImage, and then close the context.

Another way is a new API that will capture a snapshot of a view hierarchy. One of the new methods to capture a snapshot is `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates`. That creates specialized snapshot view.

Comment: Thank you so much Duncan, reading your comments along with the code TwoStraws is presenting on this thread is really helpful and insightful to understand the situation better . I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

swift 3

```
    let screen = UIScreen.main

    if let window = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(screen.bounds.size, false, 0);
        window.drawHierarchy(in: window.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: false)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        let composeSheet = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeFacebook)
        composeSheet?.setInitialText("Hello, Facebook!")
        composeSheet?.add(image)

        present(composeSheet!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```